# Nhibernate QueryOver. OrderBy using strings property names.

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I'm refactoring old-style query `CreateCriteria()` to `QueryOver()`. My Wcf service gets `string PropertyName` to order queries results. For `IQueryable` I use Dynamic LINQ to do such ordering, for `CreateCriteria()` - `AddOrder()`.

```
IList<object[]> result =
            GetSession()
                .QueryOver(() => activity)
                .JoinAlias(() => activity.ActivityLicense, () => license)
                .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.Count<Activity>(e => e.Id), "ActivityCount")
                            .Add(Projections.Group(() => license.SerialNumber), "SerialNumber")
                            .Add(Projections.Count<Activity>(e => e.MacAdress), "MacAddressCount")
                            .Add(Projections.Count<Activity>(e => e.IpAdress), "IpAddressCount")
                )
                .OrderByAlias("ActivityCount") // Compilation Error - I need such extension method
                .List<object[]>();
```

Any suggestions how to do ordering in case with string property names?

PS: I could not use LINQ to Nhibernate: [LINQ to NHibernate - .GroupBy().Skip().Take() cause an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879828/linq-to-nhibernate-groupby-skip-take-cause-an-exception)

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can always get the `UnderlyingCriteria`...

```
var q = GetSession()
                .QueryOver(() => activity)
                .JoinAlias(() => activity.ActivityLicense, () => license)
                .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.Count<Activity>(e => e.Id), "ActivityCount")
                            .Add(Projections.Group(() => license.SerialNumber), "SerialNumber")
                            .Add(Projections.Count<Activity>(e => e.MacAdress), "MacAddressCount")
                            .Add(Projections.Count<Activity>(e => e.IpAdress), "IpAddressCount")
                );


q.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new Order("ActivityCount", true));

var results = q.List();
```

or as an extension method for IQueryOver

```
public static IQueryOver<T,T> OrderByAlias(this IQueryOver<T,T> q, string aliasName, bool ascending)
{
    q.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new Order(aliasName, ascending));
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to turn ICriteria back to IQueryOver?

Comment: I don't think so, what you could do is refactor that into an IQueryOver extension method. I'll post example...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the OrderBy directly from the QueryOver API by passing in `Projections.Property(propName)`, for example:

```
var query = GetSession()
                .QueryOver<Activity>()
                .OrderBy(Projections.Property("ActivityCount").Desc;
```

There is no way to set the direction by a string, so you'll have to do a simple if/else or create an extension method to simplify the API.

Comment: .Desc property does not exist